# Android Retrofit how sort request

Tags: android, retrofit

I get the data from the api and I want to get not all , but only cafes, restaurants etc. I read about the @Query but dint understend it. Tell me pls how to do it ? Thank you.

Retrofit:

```
public class Retrofit {

private static final String ENDPOINT = "http://gdetut.com/api";
private static ApiInterface apiInterface;

interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/firms?salt=63926e380bdc96ef990d57898daeb71c&category_id=1")
    void getPlaces(Callback<List<Places>> callback);


}

static {
    init();
}

private static void init() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .build();
    apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
}

public static void getPlaces (Callback<List<Places>> callback) {
    apiInterface.getPlaces(callback);
}

}
```

In Activity:

```
Retrofit.getPlaces(new Callback<List<Places>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Places> places, Response response) {


            listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, places));


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to choose subcategory_id = 1 ?
Try to change

```
//init and call
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(ENDPOINT)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .build();
apiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
Call<List<Places>> call = ApiInterface.getPlaces("1");
call.enqueue(this);

//interface
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/firms?salt=63926e380bdc96ef990d57898daeb71c&category_id=1")
Call<List<Places>> getPlaces(@Query("subcategory_id") String cat);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<List<Places>> call, Response<List<Places>> response) {

    System.out.println("response " + response.toString());
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<List<Places>> call, Throwable t) {

}
```

Comment: Dont working, dont see the enqueue in Call<List<Places>> call = ApiInterface.getPlaces("1");
call.enqueue(this);

Comment: Your response is at onResponse, watch my edited answer.